# Is it possible to create a component tag that includes another component tag like in HTML - ReactJS, NextJS

Tags: reactjs, components, next.js13

Let's say we have two components :

- Component1
- Component2

Can we place them into the code with this kind of a style:

```
<Component1>
  <Component2>
  </Component2>
</Component1>
```

Comment: It is possible to do in react.js as well as next.js . This is called JSX style coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a React component that accepts two React components as children by using the props.children property. You can pass any number of children to a component by nesting them inside the component’s opening and closing tags.
Here is an example of how you can do it:

```
import React from "react";


function ParentComponent(props) {
  return <div>{props.children}</div>;
}

function ChildComponent1() {
  return <div>This is Child Component 1.</div>;
}

function ChildComponent2() {
  return <div>This is Child Component 2.</div>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <ParentComponent>
      <ChildComponent1 />
      <ChildComponent2 />
    </ParentComponent>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In this example, the ParentComponent accepts two child components - ChildComponent1 and ChildComponent2. The ParentComponent renders both of these components using the props.children property.